# Best tech for receiving 50000 emails and sending to azure service bus

Tags: email, azure, azureservicebus

I'm looking for a robust solution that can receive 50000 emails, strip out the attachment, and some metadata and add an item to an azure service bus for processing.

At the moment we are using a temp solution running an outlook email client on an azure VM but we are only processing 100 emails. This is not a future proof solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is some code that does listen for SMTP Traffic on port 25. 
There is a great article on doing this with Azure that contains code examples: 
http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure

Basically, the idea is that you can spin up loads of recipients to take away the emails to the point where 50 000 emails is just a matter of how many servers you're willing to spin up.

I would even look into the Azure Service Fabric for a scalable application environment (unlike docker who does containerization) to scale in/out the need for email processor:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/service-fabric/

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I don't think I'll get a better answer than that.